# Execute Stored procedure in SSIS n Number of times

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I have DataFlowTask. Behind it, I have OLEDBSource (with a select statement), feeding into OLEDBCommand (with a stored procedure).

This successfully helps me execute stored procedure for each row in the select statement.

How can I run the above DataFlowTask n Number of time?

Comment: SSIS has a for and a for each loop in the controlflow.  place your dataflow within the loop in the control flow

Comment: Isn't this exactly what you were experiencing in your [question earlier](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29520255/execute-stored-procedure-for-each-row-in-the-table-in-ssis) and that's not what you wanted?

Comment: billinkc, no.. I want to execute the whole process n Number of times. My earlier question was different

Comment: In your previous question, where you had a foreach loop container, use a for loop container.